# #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Solution Guys...

FYI i am using xampp to use phpmyadmin. and this error happens during the process of creating a database on localhost. Below is the code for config.inc file under phpmyadmin directory:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE      AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to run the create_tables.sql inside the examples/ folder on phpMyAdmin to create the tables needed for the advanced features. That or disable those features by commenting them on the config file.

Comment: as i am a beginner, would you please be able to show me step by step as i am not sure about what to disable in the config file nor how to run create_tables.sql

Comment: the error is resolved by commenting out the last 4 lines of the config.php file, as in 4 cfg statements. is that what u meant?

Comment: That's an alternative, yes. For imorting the .sql file, you should go to the import tab on phpmyadmin and select that file, and then send the form. Just that :)

Comment: I found the create_tables.sq.gz file in /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/ on Ubuntu

Comment: If issue not solved: check twice if your pma__table_something does not have double underscore. String replace it with single in sql before executing, works.

Comment: You can run on the shell: `locate create_tables.sql` to locate the script on your system.

Comment: this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/master/examples/create_tables.sql

Comment: This solutions doesn't run in all cases, answer below by Andrea Perdicchia is the right one. sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Comment: @EnriMR afaik, that solution only works if using a debian based distro (like ubuntu, or well, debian). But I agree, on those distros, that's the right choice.

Answer (score 80):

i've resolved with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Comment: This solved it for me! Finding a simple solution on a Vagrant VM was hard, but this did it!

Comment: Worked for me as well! When wizard asks you if you want to re-install the phpmyadmin table answer yes.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too.

Comment: What if I'm using windows?

Answer (score 19):

> "You have to run the create_tables.sql inside the examples/ folder on phpMyAdmin to create the tables needed for the advanced features. That or disable those features by commenting them on the config file".

```
/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/
```

Only to complete de choosed answer, this is the path to the examples/ directory on Ubuntu.

Just use the import feature and choose "create_tables.sql.gz".

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problem but none of your answers solved it. But I found [this link](http://yuvrajingale.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma_table_uiprefs-doesnt-exist/). I had to edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
```

**into**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs’;
```

My problem was solved, hope it can help others.

Comment: It should be "\_" not "\_\_".

Comment: Actually Ryan, the double underscores ( `__` )is correct because that's the correct table name prefix used in the `create_tables.sql` file. Otherwise it won't work. That's what had happened with me. I had done everything except mind those two underscores in the table name prefix.

Answer (score 15):

You will find `create_tables.sql.gz` file in `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/` dir

[image]

Extract it and  change `pma_` prefix by `pma__` or vice versa

[image]

Then import you new script SQL :

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After I downloaded phpmyadmin from their website, I extracted the `create_tables.sql` file from the **examples folder** and then I imported it from the **'Import'** tab of phpmyadmin.
It creates the database 'phpmyadmin' and the relevant table within.

This step might not be needed as the 12 tables were already there...
The problem seemed to be the double underscore in the tables' names.

I edited `'config.inc.php'` and added another underscore (`__`) after the `'pma_'` prefix of the tables.

ie.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
```

became

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complete the answer - on Ubuntu/Mint you can just run:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz | mysql
```

(of course this assumes development environment where your default mysql user is root and you use no password; in other case use `| mysql -uuser_name -p`)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it just in **1 second**!

just use this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Answer (score 2):

I shear the point made by user2237829. The table names in the create_tables script used a double underscore while the table names in the xampp example uses a single underscore.

Answer (score 2):

This one just worked for me....

The error message displayed is:

```
“# 1146 – Table ‘phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs’ doesn’t exist“
```

on your programme files,locate the configuration file `config.inc.php` phpmyadmin

Then trace the file `$Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs’;`

and replace it to the code : `$cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pma__table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs’;`

restart your XAMMP and start localhost

solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1175137) on Linux Debian. I solved using the create_tables.sql in the [official package](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php) and changing pma_ with pma__ inside /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem..
I tried everything solution in google, but still error.

But, now i resolved it.

I've resolved with make give double slash like that:

```
//$cfg['Servers'][1]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
```

It works!!

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the line with the following setting

```
$cfg['Servers'][1]['table_uiprefs']
```

Its not really an elegant solution, but it worked for my needs. (Just getting a basic PMA for running queries etc without UI customization).

Please do this only if you do not care about UI Prefs. If not, other people have answered this question very well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
```

Change into:

```
$Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs’;
```

Then
https://kamalkaur188.wordpress.com/category/removing-error-1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma_recent-doesnt-exist/ work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to drop database phpmyadmin and run sql/create_tables.sql script.
Just login to mysql console and:

```
DROP DATABASE phpmyadmin;
\. {your path to pma}/sql/reate_tables.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

in your unix/linux/Mac console

Comment: Yes i can confirm this solution (Attention it will recreate all phpmyadmin database).

Answer (score -2):

You can also find create_tables.sql file it [phpMyAdmin's repo](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/examples/create_tables.sql). Just import it from phpMyAdmin panel. It should work.

Comment: `create_tables.sql` file is part of phpMyAdmin's **installation process**! You should not use in on an existing and working installation of pmA. Plus: You should never download a particular file from a repository. Always clone _entire_ repository!