# #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Unlike many of the other questions that have been asked - I have just opened PHPMYadmin and before I can do anything this message crops up.

I haven't changed anything, I haven't deleted any files. I just haven't accessed it for a while.

How do I get back to my database?

Comment: Hope [this][1] link will help you...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-recent-doesnt-exist

Comment: I don't have an examples folder in my phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If your are using easyPHP, the examples folder with the necessary file is located in folder like

> **EasyPHP\modules\phpmyadmin3522x130318184029\examples**