# phpMyAdmin is looking in the wrong DB for PMA_Tracking etc

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I recently did something stupid and then compounded it with another idiot move and now I am stuck.

I allowed phpMyAdmin to create it's tables in an important DB I was working on. Of course being a fool I panicked and dropped the tables. Now despite having a vanilla config file that makes no mention of the DB and having removed all the phpMyAdmin files and unpacked them again I am still getting error messages about the table not existing in the wrong DB.

As per [#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-recent-doesnt-exist) I have imported the make tables SQL but this has not helped.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what phpMyAdmin has written and where to make this problem so persistent but I am starting to loose my cool...

How do I make it look in the right place? I've updated the `config.inc.php` and outright told it that where to look and still it wants to use the DB I am trying to build for my project.

```
 /* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
```

What am I missing to make it want to look in `MyOtherDB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly the same thing happened to me :0)  I figured out that the settings are stored in cookies. Just use our browser inspection tools to delete all the pma_* cookies.