# MySQL Error #1146 can't get rid of deleted tables

Tags: mysql

I know #1146 has been asked too many times, but my case is a bit different, so please bear with me.

I was trying to delete a database "libdb_bak" as I no longer need the backup db, however, some error happened and PHPMyadmin asked me to create something related to "pma" thing - I didn't paid attention to the details, and after confirming the operation, I go on to my other tasks.

After returning to PHPMyAdmin, the operation seems failed, so I go to C:\AppServ\MySQL\data\ to delete the database manually, now every time I tried to go into any database, it will fail with error message regarding "libdb_bak.pma_tracking" doesn't exists.

I tried uninstalling AppServ (AppServ: 8.6.0 includes MySQL:5.7.17, PHPMyAdmin: 4.6.6) and deleted the whole AppServ directory (clean delete, nothing left in Recycle Bin), restart PC, re-install AppServ, and the problem still exists - it is still looking for the libdb_bak.pma_tracking file, which, it is not supposed to remember, since I already done a clean wipe and fresh re-install.

Can anyone help me to locate the residue of this file location memory, so that I can get rid of it for good? I can't use my PC to continue my work, as long as this problem still exists. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, the culprit is the cookies! Cleared my browser history for the last few hours and the problem goes away.

Thanks to Batman's answer, recreating db with the same error leads me to investigate other options and found the solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one: [#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12760394/8187501)

Btw, Have you tried creating table "libdb_bak" from the terminal or Work Bench/Heidisql etc? And see if recreating the data files solves the issue.

Comment: If you think that this is a duplicate of the other question, click the flag button under the post and click `a duplicate...` then you just insert the link of the previous question  `;)`

Comment: tried recreating the db, still looking for the libdb_bak.pma_tracking file. I suspect it is stored in some sort of cookie file, since I cleaned the registry of anything related with MySQL.